# ASP.NET start service programmatically access denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, service

I'm building a ASP.NET MVC application, when a user logs in as admin (not windows authentication, admin for this application only) they need to have the ability to start and stop a service. I'm getting access denied every time I attempt this programmatically, the service runs as localsystem. Is it possible to use the `ServiceController` to start a windows service as a specific user that does have the correct permissions? There are a few threads on this but none have answered my question. See code below:

```
private static System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController svc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("CanCam Review Service");

public static void StartService()
{
    string[] args = new string[] { Configuration.databaseConnectionString, Configuration.intervalInSeconds.ToString(), Configuration.packetLimit.ToString(), Configuration.suspectedHackTimeOutInSeconds.ToString(), Configuration.writeToFile.ToString(), Configuration.path, Configuration.maxFileAgeInDays.ToString() };

    if (serviceStatus == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            svc.Start(args);
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to allow a non-administrator (not server admin) to start and stop services and on top of that I believe that IIS adds a layer of security that disallows it because it is a very BAD idea, from a security standpoint, to expose control of a server's services through the web.

Comment: You would have to pass in the credentials.

Comment: You could have another service that's always running that's running with the correct permissions that's responsible for starting/stopping the service. The user facing application would make a call to this service in order to perform the starting/stopping.

Comment: Thanks all, Kevin raises a good point, this does sound like the start of a major security flaw. I will look at other methods to carrying this out, another service as mason has mentioned or possibly polling the database for new config from the original service. Appreciate the advice.